# Are ORA-01234 tags too specific to be useful?

Tags: discussion, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do we really need a tag for every error code?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66352/do-we-really-need-a-tag-for-every-error-code)

I just found two questions with unique tags:

- ora-02289
- ora-02298

I removed those tags from those questions ([SO 1320593](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320593/error-ora-06550-ora-00933), [SO 4702310](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702310/sql-error-ora-02298-cannot-validate-system-aeropuerto-fk-parent-keys-not-fo)).

As I was doing that clean-up and then asking this question, I also found tags:

- [ora-00933](/questions/tagged/ora-00933) with 9 questions.
- [ora-00904](/questions/tagged/ora-00904) with 32 questions.
- [ora-00900](/questions/tagged/ora-00900) with 10 questions.
- [ora-06550](/questions/tagged/ora-06550) with 10 questions.

Should there be a policy stance on tags about a specific error code in a product?  Or was I too trigger-happy in deleting the singleton tags?

Comment: Closely related - the problem is resurgent, perhaps.  The other question cited listed many, many ora-01234 codes, but a search on tags only showed the 4 still around - so there was a cleanup done, and then entropy resumed its normal course and they started reappearing.

Comment: It's still better to keep this all consolidated. I'd update the other question with an updated Oracle error list, so all the discussion around the topic (it is very specific, regardless of each tag name) in one place.